# Use JavaScript variable in html

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am creating a web page wherein the user can play the audio found on the url he entered.

For this I am first taking an input from the user, storing in a variable in JavaScript and then need to use the entered URL back in my html.

My JavaScript and html codes:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function loader()
{
  var inpt=document.getElementById("userInput").value;               
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="loader()">

**use the value of inpt here**
```

I cannot figure out how to use the input url back in the html. Am I doing something wrong ?

Also, is there any better way of doing this.

**Edit:**
What I am actually doing is trying to use the entered url in place of "/media/demo.wav" in this code:

```js
<div class="list-group" id="playlist">
<a href=""
ng-class="{ 'list-group-item': true, active: isPlaying('../media/demo.wav') }"
ng-click="play('../media/demo.wav')">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
*song name*
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see my update @Swapnil. I think it is a better solution than doing an attribute replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `div` and use JavaScript to populate the HTML inside the `div`. Here is what it might look like:

HTML:

```
<div id="audioplayer"></div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('audioplayer').innerHTML = "audio player code"+inpt+"other audio player code";
```

**Update:**

You shouldn't be doing an attribute replace. Just wrap all that code in the `audioplayer` div, and set the innerHTML like what I showed you earlier:

JavaScript:

```
var audioplayerInnerHTML = '<div class="list-group" id="playlist">';
audioplayerInnerHTML .= '<a href="" ng-class="{ \'list-group-item\': true, active: isPlaying(\'..'+inpt+'\') }" ng-click="play(\'..'+inpt+'\')">';
audioplayerInnerHTML .= '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>';
audioplayerInnerHTML .= '*song name*';
audioplayerInnerHTML .= '</a>';
audioplayerInnerHTML .= '</div>';

document.getElementById('audioplayer').innerHTML = audioplayerInnerHTML;
```

Comment: in the last line of your code you have written 'audioplayer' as the element's id. but where is it ? Do I have to make it in html ? how?

Comment: I already posted the HTML in the original response. It is just an empty div with id of "audioplayer". The contents of the div are populated using the JavaScript .innerHTML function.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code:

```js
function loader() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("userInput").value;               
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="loader()">
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Update**

For achieving what you said in your edit, you can use the code below:

```
var attr = document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").getAttribute('ng-class');
attr = attr.replace("../media/demo.wav", WHATEVERE_YOU_WANT);
document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").setAttribute("ng-class", attr);
```

Comment: just to confirm, can I place my inpt variable in place of WHATEVER_YOU_WANT ?
Like this: attr=attr.replace("../media/demo.wav",inpt);

Comment: I tried what you told but nothing happens. The audio file once loaded doesn't change.

Comment: So. Try using jquery to remove the audio tag and create a new one. You can do it with javascript too. jqruey makes it easier

Comment: can you please tell me in detail what you meant by that ? actually i'm new to all this!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="loader();" value="do">

<div id="placeholder">**use the value of inpt here**</div>

<script>
function loader()
{
  var inpt = document.getElementById("userInput").value; 
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=inpt;  
}
</script>
```

Try here
https://jsfiddle.net/Menda0/e7phd00g/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can go about this. Here are some examples.

**Regular Javascript:** fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/onfpg0d6/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loader() {
        var input = document.getElementById( "userInput" ).value;
        document.getElementById( "result" ).innerHTML = input;
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="loader();">
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Using jQuery:** fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vbbow5ue/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#submit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery("#result").html( jQuery("#userInput").val() );
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Using AngularJS:** fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8LLn3chv/

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" id="userInput" ng-model="userInput">
    <p>{{userInput}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your update try something like this.

```
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="loader();" value="do">

<div class="list-group" id="playlist">
<a id="thing" href=""
ng-class="{ 'list-group-item': true, active: isPlaying('../media/demo.wav') }"
ng-click="play('../media/demo.wav')">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
*song name*
</a>
</div>

<script>
function loader()
{
  var inpt = document.getElementById("userInput").value; 
  document.getElementById("thing").setAttribute("ng-click", "play('"+ inpt+"')");
}
</script>
```

Jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Menda0/e7phd00g/